# angularjs inserting different HTML templates on different conditions

Tags: angularjs

My HTML has following part:

```
<div ng-if="body">
  <div align="center">
    <h3>Body</h3>
    ...
  </div>  
</div>

<div ng-if="memory">
  <div align="center">
  <h3>Memory game</h3> <=
  </div>  
</div>
```

The first div where `ng-if="body"` has a fixed HTML and I just change model values to have dynamic view.

In this second div where `ng-if="memory"` I want to insert different templates which are in different HTML files, based on a condition(perhaps defined in my controller?)

My controller has something like following:

```
var exerciseType = Number($stateParams.exerciseId);
    console.log("Exe type from client: "+ exerciseType);
    if(exerciseType===1 ||exerciseType===3|| exerciseType===5 || 
        exerciseType===7 || exerciseType===9 || exerciseType===11 || exerciseType===12){
        $scope.body=true
    }
    else if(exerciseType===2){
        $scope.memory=true
    }
```

***To give more insights***: On the parent page I have an accordion list of exercises, which is a mixture of body related and memory related exercises and on clicking on a list element it's corresponding exercise page is loaded. That's why those `$stateParams.exerciseId` 
Now the body related exercises have same structure and hence they have a common HTML: just the model values change for different body related exercises.

On the other hand, memory related exercises each has totally different logic and hence each exercise has it's own HTML.

**Route**:

```
.state('tab.plan', {
      url: '/plan',
       resolve: {
        authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
          return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
        }],
      },
      views: {
        'tab-plan': {
          templateUrl: '/templates/tab-plan.html', <= my accordion list
          controller: 'planCtrl'
        }
      },
      cache: false
    })

    .state('tab.exercise', {
      url: '/plan/:exerciseId', //:dayId/:exerciseId
       resolve: {
        authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
          return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
        }],
      },
      views: {
        'tab-plan': {
          templateUrl: '/templates/video.html', <= page where exercises are loaded, the first code snippet is from this page!
          controller: 'videoCtrl'
        }
      },
       cache: false
    })
```

**How can I do it?**

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: I am not quite sure how I can insert such diifferent HTML? ng-include seems like an option, but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using ng-include:

```
<div ng-if="memory">
  <div align="center">
  <h3>Memory game</h3>
  <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
  </div>  
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
var exerciseType = Number($stateParams.exerciseId);
    console.log("Exe type from client: "+ exerciseType);
    if(exerciseType===1 ||exerciseType===3|| exerciseType===5 || 
        exerciseType===7 || exerciseType===9 || exerciseType===11 || exerciseType===12){
        $scope.body=true
    }
    else if(exerciseType===2 || exerciseType===4){
        $scope.memory=true
        if(exerciseType===2){
            $scope.template="./templates/template1.html"
        }
        if(exerciseType===4){
            $scope.template="./templates/template2.html"
        }
    }
```

And I created two HTML templates template1.html and template2.html